# Краткое прилагательное и наречие: как отличить?

Tags: части-речи

Краткое прилагательное и наречие очень близки, но всё-таки их можно различать. По идее, краткое прилагательное всегда относится к существительному, а наречие — к глаголу: «цветок красив» и «идти медленно».

Но следующие предложения никак не вписываются в эту схему: «Всё стало глухо кругом» и «Становится прохладнее». Причём, в первом случае "глухо" — прилагательное, а "прохладнее" — наречие. Почему так, и какому правилу подчиняется эта закономерность?

Answer (score 3):

> краткое прилагательное всегда относится к существительному, а наречие к глаголу

Лучше не скажешь. Ну, может ещё прилагательное относиться к местоимению. Главное теперь: узнать существительное и глагол.

Answer (score 1):

Почему же не вписываются? Смысл предложения "Все стало глухо кругом" в том, что "все глухо", но было так не всегда, а только с определенного момента имееет место быть. То есть прилагательное "глухо" относится к местоимению "все", несмотря на то что оно составляет составное именное сказуемое совместно с глаголом "стало". Второе предложение, по-моему, вообще не требует комментариев. Глагол и наречие - все как по нотам.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сравнить: (1) Погода становится прохладной (прохладнее). - (2)Становится прохладно (прохладнее).

Семантика одинаковая, а грамматика разная. В первом случае прилагательное относится к существительному и согласуется с ним, а во втором случае субъект действия отсутствует, это безличное предложение, именная часть сказуемого выражена предикативным наречием.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, трудность связана с тем, что обе краткие формы входят в составное именное сказуемое. Чем выражена именная часть?

"Все стало каким? каково?-(глухим) глухо кругом"-прилагательное, т. к. обозначает качество предмета, выраженного местоимением ВСЁ.

"Становится каково? -прохладнее". -в школе - категория состояния, в вузе-предикативное наречие. Оно не имеет значения признака действия или признака какого-либо другого признака, как обычное наречие(идти медленно,очень медленно),оно обозначает СОСТОЯНИЕ природы или человека, иногда такие наречия называют «безлично-предикативными словами» (предикативами).

Answer (score -2):

Наречием называют **состояние** существительного, а вот за прилагательное принято считать свойство, признак, качество. Холодно — это **состояние** человека, сегодня — это состояние дня и т. п., а прилагательное только характеризует предмет или называет его свойство. Ни одно прилагательное не может назвать состояние, ни одно наречие не может назвать свойство.

Comment: Вы  в сообществе для любителей русского языка и лингвистов. Если вы хотите, чтобы ваши ответы воспринимали всерьёз, то не стоит лениться расставлять знаки препинания и заглавные буквы.